# What are Hydrators in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I was going through the Hydrators in zend Framework 2 but I failed to understand it properly. What are Hydrators in ZF2contained in **Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator** class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read through the [official Documentation about `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html), this will give you enough insight about what these things are.

In short: they are classes that you use to have an `inputFormat` turn into an `outputFormat` going by some specification. For example you can turn an `array` into `instanceof SomeClass`  or vice versa, using either public keys or public setter functions.